# Concatenating videos using ffmpeg writes over empty audio stream

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have 4 movie files that I am trying to overlay and concatenate:

1. Intro file with an empty audio channel (generated using lavfi)
2. Main movie file(s) that need to be concatenated and trimmed
3. Watermark that needs to be overlaid on top of 2
4. An outro movie that also has an empty channel.

Here is the command I am using to do all this:

```
ffmpeg -i temp_intro.mp4 -f concat -i tempFile.txt -i scoreboard.mp4 -i temp_outro.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1]trim=end=24:start=12[s0];[s0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s1];[1]atrim=end=24:start=12[s2];[s2]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s3];\
[s1][s3]concat=a=1:n=1:v=1[s4];\
[2]format=yuva444p[s5];[s5]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[s6];\
[s4][s6]overlay=eof_action=repeat:x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=main_h-overlay_h-20[s7];\
[0][s7][3]concat=n=3[s8]" test.mp4
```

Despite how ugly it looks, it mostly works - except for the audio. The audio starts playing as soon as the intro clip starts. I cannot create an output file with the overlaid movie because I also need to add fade-out and fade-in effects for the intro and outro. I can only re-encode once since I will be doing this over multiple large files every night.

Please suggest how I might be able to fix the audio issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is easy - just need to concatenate audio and video for the file explicitly in the second concat. Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i temp_intro.mp4 -f concat -i tempFile.txt -i scoreboard.mp4 -i temp_outro.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1]trim=end=24:start=12[s0];[s0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s1];[1]atrim=end=24:start=12[s2];[s2]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s3]; \
[2]format=yuva444p[s4];[s4]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[s5]; \
[s1][s5]overlay=eof_action=repeat:x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=main_h-overlay_h-20[s7]; \
[0:v:0][0:a:0] [s7][s3] [3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[s8]" -map [s8] test.mp4
```